# What are the possible programatic ways to simplify the If Conditions (re-write Condition)

Tags: php, parsing, expression

I have a if condition `if(abc==xyz AND (xyz==jkl OR abc==jkl))`.

How can I rewrite this expression with code that will give me non-brackets condition, i.e. something like

```
if(xyz==jkl OR abc==jkl  AND abc==xyz)`
```

For basic expression, we can use prefix notations where based on precedence of operator with help of stack we can solve it. But I just want to rewrite the condition in order to find which would give the same output as the one with parentheses.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by removing the parens?

Comment: The brackets are actually can assist in reading the code later.

Comment: `OR(abc==jkl)` These parentheses are somewhat meaningless. An example where their absense changes the result (and php code, since it's tagged as php) would make your question clearer - most importantly it's not clear what  you are doing, or why.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have to parse the condition after removing parens. The tool I'm using it takes simplified expressions (non-parens).

Comment: @AD7six the example is just a reference what I want to achieve is a expression in a logical sequence (in which they should execute) without parenthesis. I have a tool which takes condition without parenthesis. I hope it will help you to understand the issue.

Comment: given that `abc==xyz` _has_ to be true for the condition to be met, doesn't that make the sub `OR abc==jkl` meaningless anyway?

Comment: @JamesThorpe This condition can be anything.. I think I gave a wrong example to explain :) my bad!! As I mentioned in above comments my tool doesn't take a expression with brackets in between so I have change the sequence (in given example it doesn't require but in many cases it will) of it to create a new condition.

Comment: `The tool` what tool? Please consider providing an example that makes sense mandatory.

Comment: @AD7six I'm reading this expression  as String from excel and to excute this I have to parse it ie. those xyz,abc etc will be replaced by its value (till here it will be a String which I can't evaluate directly) Now the main part start where I'm stucked. The tool which I developed is parsing the normal expressions without parens but it should do the parens parts also, so what I'm thinking if I can re-write the condition and remove parens than rest will be the same.

Comment: `The tool which I developed` - I think you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @AD7six Sorry, I don't know how to explain this in more details.. simplest I way I can ask is `How can we re-write the a expression without parenthesis`.. anyways Thanks for your time :) May be next time I will come up with some clear cut question :D

Answer (score 2):

You can start by converting the condition to [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), using the fact that AND has higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than OR:

```
if (abc==xyz AND xyz==jkl OR abc==xyz AND abc==jkl)
```

Looking at the second part, this may be rewritten to

```
if (abc==xyz AND xyz==jkl OR abc==xyz AND xyz==jkl)
```

Now you can see that both parts are the same, really, i.e. we can simplify to

```
if (abc==xyz AND xyz==jkl)
```

---

Fun fact: if the expression couldn't be simplified, you could also combine `||` and `AND`, leveraging the precedence rules:

```
if (abc==xyz AND xyz==jkl || abc==jkl)
```

Not that I would recommend it.

Comment: `you could also combine ||` Why use the other OR operator, `||` and OR are aliases of each other.. no?

Comment: They do the same logical operation, but have different precedence. Check out the [precedence table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: What about parens ?? I'm re-writing it to remove parenthesis while re-ordering the expressions inside condition that part should also be taken care.. or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mifeet you mean in case of logical operations it will give the same output (with/out parenthesis)

Comment: heh I always favor parentheses (and use `||` and `&&`) to avoid ambiguity, hence I didn't notice that subtlety. `Looking at the second part, this may be rewritten to` it's not clear to me what that means - it's not equivalent to the first version in the answer ([only the name changes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq9GI.png)), though the final simplified version (the "that expression has unmatchable permutations") is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The condition `(abc==xyz AND xyz==jkl)` is logically equivalent to your original condition and obviously doesn't contain any parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If are asking for specifically this condition which say that true if abc,xyz,jkl are equal to each other

So

if(abc==jkl AND abc==xyz).

And if you looking for experiment than you to see the Operator Precedence table http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php